# How to remove square brackets [] after extracting response using json path extractor?

Tags: jmeter

I have used Json Path Extractor to extract value of Cid. The value is 1034.

When I pass this variable to next HTTP request it goes like [1034].

My question is, how to remove these [] square brackets and pass only the numeric value to the next HTTP Request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you're using [JSON Path Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) here are the options:

   - add `[0]` to your JSON Path query
   - access extracted value as `${Cid_1}` (given you use `Cid` as a "Reference Name"

See "JSON Arrays" chapter of the [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) guide for details

2. If you're using JSON Path PostProcessor you can control the match group via "Match Numbers" input.

You can see resulting variable(s) values using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

[image: JSON Path View Results Tree]

Answer (score 1):

In Jmeter 4.0 version its okay to use `$..token_id`,
but in Jmeter 2.x version we need to use `$.token_id`

i.e, there should be only one dot(.) after $,

I faced the issue and now its working.