# Accessing User Variable, BSF scripting in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, web-application, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to access a variable named **var1** in the below BSF Script,
where var1 is extracted from JSON XPath Extractor:

```
String abc= vars.get("var1");
abc = abc.replaceAll("^[\"\\(\\[]+|[\"\\)\\(]]+$", "");
vars.put("abc",abc);
```

After running the script I could not fetch the value of the variable, i.e. the `abc` variable.

I have referred to 
[How to remove square brackets [] after extracting response using json path extractor?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22609/how-to-remove-square-brackets-after-extracting-response-using-json-path-extra) but could not get the value.

My Jmeter version is 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a Debug Sampler, and analysed the result at Response data. I found  Jmeter creates a new variable `Var_1`, which resolved my problem & can be used for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this line, your regex is a little bit flaky:

```
abc = abc.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
```

Also consider switching to [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://groovy-lang.org/) as it is the most powerful and performing scripting option as of now, check out [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for details.

Comment: If this is your article, please say so, so your answer is not flagged as spam.